''plot.phylo'' builds a phylogenetic tree
I'm having trouble visualizing an evolutionary tree.In my  otus_tree.nwks, there are a total of 25 phylum, I filtered out 12 phylum, and the rest were classified as Others. Now I want to visualize the evolutionary tree containing 12 phylum. I assigned an exclusive color to each of these 12 phylum, but in the end only the colors of 8 phylum are displayed. The final troubleshooting found that the color abundance of Acidobacteria in the edge_color file was abnormal. Acidobacteria occupied 13,188 out of a total of 22,091 branches. How should I deal with this? Below is my R code
otutab <- read.csv("otutab_info.csv")
otu_tree <- ape::read.tree("otus.nwk")
OTU_taxa <- otutab[,c(1,230)]
phylums <- OTU_taxa %>% pull(Phylum) %>% unique()
phylums
[1] "Proteobacteria"              "Actinobacteria"              "Firmicutes"                  "Unassigned"                  "Deinococcus-Thermus"        
 [6] "Bacteroidetes"               "Gemmatimonadetes"            "Acidobacteria"               "Verrucomicrobia"             "Chloroflexi"                
[11] "Planctomycetes"              "Nitrospirae"                 "Ignavibacteriae"             "Latescibacteria"             "Candidatus_Saccharibacteria"
[16] "Spirochaetes"                "Armatimonadetes"             "Aminicenantes"               "Fibrobacteres"               "BRC1"                       
[21] "Chlamydiae"                  "Euryarchaeota"               "Fusobacteria"                "Parcubacteria"               "Hydrogenedentes"    

OTU_taxa %>% 
group_by(Phylum) %>% 
summarise(n()) %>%
print(n=Inf)
# A tibble: 25 × 2
   Phylum                      `n()`
   <chr>                       <int>
 1 Acidobacteria                1054
 2 Actinobacteria               2835
 3 Aminicenantes                   4
 4 Armatimonadetes                15
 5 BRC1                            3
 6 Bacteroidetes                 963
 7 Candidatus_Saccharibacteria    19
 8 Chlamydiae                      2
 9 Chloroflexi                   138
10 Deinococcus-Thermus            79
11 Euryarchaeota                   1
12 Fibrobacteres                   2
13 Firmicutes                    569
14 Fusobacteria                    1
15 Gemmatimonadetes              267
16 Hydrogenedentes                 1
17 Ignavibacteriae                10
18 Latescibacteria                18
19 Nitrospirae                    38
20 Parcubacteria                   1
21 Planctomycetes                  8
22 Proteobacteria               3734
23 Spirochaetes                    5
24 Unassigned                   1201
25 Verrucomicrobia                79

a <- c("Aminicenantes","BRC1","Chlamydiae","Euryarchaeota","Fibrobacteres","Fusobacteria","Hydrogenedentes",
       "Parcubacteria","Spirochaetes","Armatimonadetes", "Candidatus_Saccharibacteria",
        "Ignavibacteriae", "Latescibacteria")  
OTU_taxa[OTU_taxa$Phylum %in% a, 'Phylum'] <- "Others"
phylum_color <- tribble(
  ~Phylum, ~color,
  "Acidobacteria","#00C9A7",
  "Gemmatimonadetes","#007554",
  "Deinococcus-Thermus","#ab5f1f",
  "Firmicutes","#FF8066",
  "Proteobacteria", "#B39CD0",
  "Actinobacteria", "#54c3ff",
  "Unassigned", "#75b831",
  "Bacteroidetes","#b04380",
  "Chloroflexi","#e69f00",
  "Nitrospirae","#114662",
  "Planctomycetes","#D5CABD",
  "Verrucomicrobia","#845EC2",
  "Others", "#a6a6a6"
) %>%
  deframe()


edge_color <- as.data.frame(otu_tree$edge)
edge_color$color <- '#a6a6a6'
phylums <- OTU_taxa %>% pull(Phylum) %>% unique()
phylums
 [1] "Proteobacteria"              "Actinobacteria"              "Firmicutes"                  "Unassigned"                  "Deinococcus-Thermus"        
 [6] "Bacteroidetes"               "Gemmatimonadetes"            "Acidobacteria"               "Verrucomicrobia"             "Chloroflexi"                
[11] "Others"                      "Nitrospirae"                 "Ignavibacteriae"             "Latescibacteria"             "Candidatus_Saccharibacteria"
[16] "Armatimonadetes"  

phylums <- phylums[-13] # Others at position 13
for (phylum_ in phylums){
     Ancestor <- getMRCA(otu_tree,OTU_taxa %>% filter(Phylum==phylum_) %>% pull(OTUID))
     Children <- getDescendants(otu_tree,node=Ancestor)
     #edge_color[edge_color$V1 %in% Children, 'color'] <- phylum_color[phylum_]
     edge_color[edge_color$V2 %in% Children, 'color'] <- phylum_color[phylum_]
    }


plot.phylo(otu_tree, type = "radial", show.tip.label=F, x.lim = c(-1,1), y.lim=c(-1,1), edge.color = edge_color$color)

I suspected that there was an error in the color specification, so I checked：phylum_color;phylum_colors;phylum_;phylums.But they match the colors I specified and I really don't know where the error is happening
phylum_color
      Acidobacteria    Gemmatimonadetes Deinococcus-Thermus          Firmicutes      Proteobacteria      Actinobacteria          Unassigned 
          "#00C9A7"           "#007554"           "#ab5f1f"           "#FF8066"           "#B39CD0"           "#54c3ff"           "#75b831" 
      Bacteroidetes         Chloroflexi         Nitrospirae      Planctomycetes     Verrucomicrobia              Others 
          "#b04380"           "#e69f00"           "#114662"           "#D5CABD"           "#845EC2"           "#a6a6a6" 
> phylum_colors
     Proteobacteria      Actinobacteria          Unassigned       Acidobacteria       Bacteroidetes          Firmicutes    Gemmatimonadetes 
          "#B39CD0"           "#54c3ff"           "#75b831"           "#00C9A7"           "#b04380"           "#FF8066"           "#007554" 
        Chloroflexi Deinococcus-Thermus         Nitrospirae      Planctomycetes     Verrucomicrobia 
          "#e69f00"           "#ab5f1f"           "#114662"           "#D5CABD"           "#845EC2" 
> phylum_
[1] "Nitrospirae"
> phylums
 [1] "Proteobacteria"      "Actinobacteria"      "Firmicutes"          "Unassigned"          "Deinococcus-Thermus" "Bacteroidetes"       "Gemmatimonadetes"   
 [8] "Acidobacteria"       "Verrucomicrobia"     "Chloroflexi"         "Planctomycetes"      "Nitrospirae" 

enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Also, consider ways of making your problem reproducible. It's much easier to help you if we can run your code. Read [mcve] for some tips.

In my evolutionary tree file, there are a total of 25 phylum, I filtered out 12 phylum, and the rest were classified as Others. Now I want to visualize the evolutionary tree containing 12 phylum. I assigned an exclusive color to each of these 12 phylum, but in the end only the colors of 8 phylum are displayed. The final troubleshooting found that the color abundance of Acidobacteria in the edge_color file was abnormal. Acidobacteria occupied 13,188 out of a total of 22,091 branches. How should I deal with this?
